# Is there a QGIS theme/project selector?

Tags: qgis

I am switching from Mapinfo Pro to QGIS and have a question. In Mapinfo, I have coded a theme selector to turn on/off themes (workspaces) in a basemap, as shown below. Has anyone made a similar plugin for QGIS, that turn on/off QGIS-projects?

Best Regards 
Jan Hvingel 
[image]

Comment: Do you mean that you want to be able to load some (background) layers from existing projects?

Answer (score 1):

There is no layer control (TOC) like QGIS plugin working on projects / workspaces. If you want menu access to single layers from a QGIS project take a look at 'Layers menu from project' plugin.

Du er velkommen til at ringe, så kan vi drøfte mulighederne......